# How to find Y on an elliptical curve in a finite field?

Tags: elliptic-curves

For example, let's use secp256k1, the curve used by bitcoin, y^2 = x^3 + 7, and x=12. Over the real numbers, that calculation is trivial - I can simply use a calculator. But in a finite field, how does it work? If I say "X is 12", how do I calculate Y? The equation (when using real numbers) almost always results in fractions. And modulo P only works with integers.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10024/finite-fields-and-ecc?rq=1 Please note that you don't divide but take inverses in the finite field (modulo the prime $p$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finite fields and ECC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10024/finite-fields-and-ecc)

Comment: I don't think the linked duplicate answers the question which seems fundamentally on how to find square roots over finite fields.

Comment: [This one is probably closer to what're your looking for though it only covers the case of the field prime $p$ being $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20636/23623)

Comment: [Alternatively the Handbook of Applied Crypto has the algorithm as Algorithm 3.34 (Chapter PDF)](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf)

Comment: SEJPM is correct. The question I should have asked is "how do I find square roots over finite fields". I have an algorithm ready to go if I can find square roots modulo P. If it is impossible to do that, then it bugs me a little bit when I read something that asserts that the same math from elliptic curves on real numbers holds true over finite fields.  If the modular math is actually the same, there should be a way to do those calculations. Perhaps our (so far) inability to come up with that math explains why the cryptography works (so far).